# Sorting not working on text_general type in solr

Tags: sorting, solr

text_general is defined as

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have another field is defined as

```
<field name="model" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

As a sample

my model name has hyphens like `"model":"ATP_JP_ATPK-000152-Y"`

Sorting is not working on this model field properly.I am not getting model names in proper ascending and descending order

sorting on model field is not working properly . I have searched a lot but still not getting proper answer . everytime i am getting same answer and i am not able to apply it . Please help

Comment: Not able to understand, what this question is tryin to ask ? Author may give more details about input and output he is getting from SOLR

Comment: Sorting doesn't work good on tokenized fields. model has been defined with text_general field type, it will be tokensized and hence the sort would not work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting doesn't work good on tokenized fields. `model` field has been defined with `text_general` field type, it will be tokenized and hence the sort would not work fine.

The sorting field should not be tokenized or uses an Analyzer that only produces a single Term,  it should use `KeywordTokenizer`

[Sorting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort)

Use string as the field type and copy the model field into the new field.